# HTC M9 Bricked...

Tags: data-recovery, stock-android

Original issue.
My cousin plugged in his HTC M9; he said it showed a count down from 5 to 1 then shut off.  To which he discovered that the charging port had visible signs of burning and smelled as such.

I replaced the charging port ribbon cable and was able to immediately start charging the phone.  However it wouldn't boot up normally.  It would boot directly to the bootloader and I could transfer from there to download mode but not into recovery to wipe cache partition.  I could also issue fastboot commands via ADB. (still virtually useless)

I tried to flash stock recovery but didn't have enough battery level on phone so had to wait.  I plugged back into wall outlet to improve charge time.

Once it reached 32% I transferred usb cable back to computer when phone instantly went blank and showed no signs of power remained.  No count down; no signs of internal damage to any area.  I didn't take the phone apart further than the case to check ribbons etc.

I thought maybe display just went out:

```
    fastboot devices
```

nothing listed.

I tried vol up+pwr button to force cycle the power only to receive audible prompt from computer that usb device was connected but no connected device shown.
I held all the buttons for more than 5 minutes while connected to computer only to receive audio prompt every so often without any visible results from phone or computer.

Device manager shows: Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM9)
Computer management:  Doesn't Shows any connected USB storage devices..

Comment: @S. Mitchell What are you​ talking about?!?

Comment: @Wayne what does the Device Manager show when you plug the phone to the computer?

Comment: Try the battery reset logic explained [here](https://www.google.co.in/amp/forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-htc-one/394469-battery-charger-reset-procedure-htc-one-m7-m8.html%3Famp) and [here](http://android-revolution-hd.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-recalibrate-battery-life-on-htc.html?m=1) - could be faulty calibration

Comment: Device manager shows:  
Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM9)  .....

Battery reset logic did nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can charge the battery outside using universal battery chargers . if the green screen is there you can flash original firmware back. if no green screen there you hawe to install boot-loader/some kind of BIOS, to chip. its in general device specific.so there comes the word bricked we can call for the device since we will need specific firmware . :D but actually its wiped device that can be restored only by original software and sometimes some specific devices programs designed to install is needed.

Comment: Unibody design makes the battery charging outside the phone a mood point.  I wouldn't even know what to purchase to make that an option.  Given the lack of function.  I haven't been able to diag it properly.  the screen hasn't lit up in any way since I last plugged into computer.